# HashMaps in Anchor

Tags: anchor, testing

Does anyone have experience using `HashMaps` in an Anchor project? 
I have the following implementation for a `struct`:

```
#[account]
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Company {
    pub id: u64, // 8 bytes
    pub authority: Pubkey, // 32 bytes
    pub name: String, // 24 bytes
    pub worker_container: HashMap<u64, bool>, // 8 * 10 = 80 bytes
    pub product_container: HashMap<u64, bool>, // (8 + 1) * 50 = 450 bytes
    pub bump: u8, // 1 byte
}
```

I can build and deploy the struct with no errors 
However, while testing on JS side I got the following error:

```
IdlError: Type not found: {"name":"workerContainer","type":{"defined":"HashMap<u64,bool>"}}
```

I don't think it's due to some serialization problems. 
According to https://github.com/near/borsh-js#type-mappings Borsch can serialize HashMaps so I wonder what the error could be.

(note: I'm aware that I could use a `Vec`, however I want to be able to check whether a key value exists quickly so I chose to use `HashMaps` instead)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, unlike Borsh; Anchor does not implement a JS type for hashmaps. See https://www.anchor-lang.com/docs/javascript-anchor-types